# Sharing on Google+ Stream after authorisation

Tags: google-plus

I have been trying to post on user's wall from my application. Even I am completed with facebook, Linkedin, Twitter. What I did is after authorising properly from these application I finally saved its token. And with that I did to post it on their wall if they are posting on my application.

Now continuing with that I want same with Google+. Though I am completed with Google+ authorisation and saved token in my DB. How can I post on Google+ on their wall or on my profile page with it. Or In google terms how can I share on user's stream.

I have tried to create box on my page and on clicking that popup window open to post on G+. What I want is if user is registered than It automatically goes to its stream not in conventional button clicking way what they have provided.

Is that Possible ??

Comment: Your have try this https://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: nanhe Miyaan... That all I have already read.

Answer (score 6):

The Google+ API does not give you write access to the user's stream.

Instead you should use:
- app activities: https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities if you want to surface the user's actions across Google
- Share plugin: https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/ for user-initiated sharing
- Interactive posts: https://developers.google.com/+/features/interactive-posts for user-initiated sharing with an explicit call-to-action and deeplinking on mobile platforms

Comment: You can also prefill the text and up to 10 recipients for a post with Interactive Posts.