# Google Plus share content

Tags: html, share, google-plus

I'm working on some social share buttons for mobile version of a website and I'm having some trouble sharing specific content through Google Plus.

What I'm doing is the following:

```
<a href="https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content=CONTENT" target="_blank" class="gplus-counter" id="gplus_share"></a>
```

I found this solution on the Internet (will provide link if I remember where exactly) and it works just fine, just without setting the content parameter of the URL and since I want to share text and link to the page I'm on, this is a problem.

Comment: This seems similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715306/sharing-on-google-stream-after-authorisation. Note that there are only two officially-supported ways to Share to Google+. Interactive posts will allow you to prefill the text of the post.

Answer (score -1):

So it appears the solution I found was a bit outdated, so I replaced the code with this and it worked well:

```
<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=URL" target="_blank" class="gplus-counter" id="gplus_share"></a>
```